# php search form using post variable to make an sql query

Tags: php, sql, forms

this is a page that displays a list of creatives, and the form offers search functionality to search by job title:

```
 if(isset($_POST['creatives-submit'])){
    $job = $_POST['job-title'];
    $data = \Db::Common($fms5->DBH)->getWhere("creatives", "creatives_active", "Yes"," AND creatives_job LIKE '%".$job."%'")->orderBy('creatives_name', 'asc');
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="creative-search">
 <input class="form-control" type="textbox" name="job-title" id="job-title" placeholder="Search by job title" />
 <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="creatives-submit" id="creatives-submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

is there anything that's obviously wrong my my code?

Comment: Does something not work? (`type="textbox"` should maybe be `type="text"`)

Comment: What are you _expecting_ the code to do?  What is it _actually_ doing?  Just posting some code and saying "does this work" is not a good way to ask a question.

Comment: Yes, so when used on the website, it just displays a completely empty page. And I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: You should add the full source code that is involved in this issue as the code provided does not give an insight of what is wrong.

Comment: @parick so the idea is the form should add the job input to the $_POST variable, which is then used in the sql query to search the database for that specific job

Comment: @solo97xyz  Right, but what do you think is happening _after that_?  What you're showing right now doesn't actually _do_ anything other than (possibly) assign results to a variable.  Nothing is then done with that result.  As @pat suggested, you should show more code.  Are the PHP and HTML in the same file?  Different files?  Where/how is `$fms5` defined?  What framework are you using?  What debugging have you already done?  Does `$job` have the value you expect?

Answer (score -2):

try changing  `if(isset($_POST['creatives-submit']))` to `if(isset($_POST['job-title']) && !empty($_POST["job-title"]))` as the form is posting the `job-title` value and this is the value you actually care about. (Since `creatives-submit` will always = `Submit`)

also change 
`<input class="form-control" type="textbox" name="job-title" id="job-title" placeholder="Search by job title" />`

to  `<input class="form-control" type="text" name="job-title" id="job-title" placeholder="Search by job title" required/>`

this means the form can't be submitted unless the `job-title` field has a value and had the correct type of `text`

Below is a modification of your code that just returns what the user searched for (Since I don't have it connected to a database)

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['job-title']) && !empty($_POST["job-title"])){
    $job = $_POST['job-title'];
    ?>
    <p>You Searched For <?php echo $job;?></p>
<?php   
}
?>
```

And the form

```
<!-- Search Form -->
<form method="post" name="creative-search">
    <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="job-title" id="job-title" placeholder="Search by job title" />
    <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="creatives-submit" id="creatives-submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

Comment: The form has two inputs.  One of them is `creatives-submit`.  There's no reason for OP to change that.

Comment: @PatrickQ but surly since they are going to be using the `job-title` value, this is what they should validate against (Check it's set and meets any other requirements). 

I've amended my answer to better show this